# How to find all possible error messages in a program?

Tags: windows-7, windows, error-logging

I'd like to find all possible error messages any piece of software can output.  Is this possible?

Using Orca.Msi, I was able to get all the error codes and their descriptions, but this only applied to the setup installer.

For the actual program, I tried using ResHack and found a few error messages from the program executables and DLL files.  The problem with this is that not all of the error messages are shown.

Is there any way to find all error messages for any given program without the source code?  In particular, programs written in C++/C#, but tips for other programming languages are welcomed.

Comment: In general, this is not possible. There are too many different ways a program can generate and display error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is using the program "Strings" which is contained in Linux and can be used on Windows through [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

It will scan your file and output every (!) possible string in your program which looks like a C-String (text, terminated with \0). Please be aware that this also outputs a lot of garbage and also non error texts contained in your file. Furthermore, it cannot determine the errorcode. 
Some examples: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/strings-command-examples/
and a manpage: https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings

You could also try to use some high level reverse engineering tool like IDA Pro but this program is really expensive (there is an old freeware version) and you have to know what you are doing since you will have to look through assember code. So this approach could tell you also the error code but requires a lot of work. So this is certainly not an automated process.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually found my solution by using Ghidra, as IDA Pro was not as affordable as I wanted it to be.